# Receiving SIG39 after machine restart

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

Everything was working correctly in our application. We rebooted our machine and after that it is receiving SIG39 (Real-time signal) right after start.

Inspecting in gdb showed almost nothing.

I set a catchpoint to catch SIG39 and also a breakpoint to sigaction and what I found was that we have sleep(900) in our application and this sleep exits immediate calling sigaction and then we receive SIG39.

But I read that sleep is interupted by real-time signal so assuming that sleep is sending SIG39 is wrong I think.

We are starting 8 threads. I read that signal 38 and 39 are used by pthread for something but I couldn't get more information about this.

I checked the system and we have a lot of free memory (100GB+) thread max is 1000000+ and

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count is 65535
ulimit -s is 8192
ulimit -v is unlimited
```

but still for some reason we get SIG39 right after start.

I have been googling a lot but I couldn't find any explanation, so I'm asking for your help, does anybody know what could cause that SIG39.

I think that it is something pthread related but can't find out more info about it nor how to fix it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is there any error number? Is it possible to share the source(error part)

Comment: we receive SIG39 and terminate, so its hard to say what is error part. The signal is send after we start our threads. The signal I think is sent from pthread internals, gdb showed that in the signal struct the field si_pid is our program pid so there has to be something wrong in pthreads internal which cause to send that signal. I think it is something external like kernel setting or something similar, because this was working before we rebooted our machine.

Comment: Does you application uses any real time signals?

Comment: no, I double checked

Comment: Programs that become buggy after a system reboot may be using unexpected new versions of shared libraries. Is it possible for you to recompile your program?

Comment: It is, we tried that but it was the same. However it is ok now, there has to be something wrong with the computer because another system reboot solved all problems. Thanks a lot for all your help and comments.